# Having symlinks in Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants (VVV) shared folders

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, symlink

I am currently using [Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) to setup local WordPress development environment in my Macbook Pro.

VVV creates separate hosts (default, develop, trunk etc) and has corresponding shared folders created inside the `/www` folder.

```
$ tree -L 1 www
www
├── default
├── phpcs
├── vvv-hosts
├── wordpress-default
├── wordpress-develop
├── wordpress-trunk
└── wp-cli
```

Instead of copying my current plugin into all the three WordPress installation's plugin folder I was to use a symlink.

Assuming that my plugin code is in `~/Dropbox/code/my-plugin`, I want to create symlinks to the following locations

- `wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`
- `wordpress-develop/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`
- `wordpress-trunk/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`

The problem with this approach is that when these folders are mapped inside the vm the symlink still points to the location in the host os which is not available inside vm. Is there any alternative to this?

I have already checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24365338/24949) from another question which deals with vagrant (not specific VVV) but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally did it by creating a new shared folder. If someone is interested then this is what I added to my own `Customfile`.

```
if vagrant_version >= "1.3.0"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/sudar/Dropbox/plugins/", "/srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins", :owner => "www-data", :mount_options => [ "dmode=775", "fmode=774" ]
else
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/sudar/Dropbox/plugins/", "/srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins", :owner => "www-data", :extra => 'dmode=775,fmode=774'
end
```

**Update**: I have also written a [blog post](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/mapping-plugin-folder-in-vvv-using-shared-folders/) explaining my setup, since a couple of people were asking about it.

Comment: I tried this but the contents of dropbox/plugins/ isn't being created. A folder will be made in the VM if it doesn't exist but it's alway empty. Any ideas? @Sudar

Comment: @DaronSpence The path that is mentioned first is the path in the host OS. The second path is the one that will be mapped inside VM. Can you post your paths?