# Files changed directly after git clone into shared folder using Vagrant on windows host

Tags: git, vagrant, symlink, git-clone

I have a windows 7 host system where I want to use a vagrant VM with the LAMP stack  [scotch box](https://box.scotch.io/). The project repository requires symlinks (*) which get changed directly after i clone the repository via ssh.

- I am cloning the repository (on guest) after connecting via `vagrant ssh`
- The repository gets cloned into the *shared folder* (**this seems to be the problem**)
- After that, `git status` (on guest) says all my symlinks have been modified

I already checked my git configurations and changed it as proposed in [answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone). Nothing helped.

**However**, when I clone the repository into an other, not shared VM folder, there are no file changes at all.

So how can I prevent that files change in the shared folder? (i'm afraid removing symlinks is not possible...)

**Edit: Example for a changed symlink**

`git diff script/zend` echoes:

```
diff --git a/script/zend b/script/zend
--- a/script/zend
--- b/script/zend
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-../source/solar/script/solar
\ No newline at end of file
```

(*) As symlinks are not allowed by default I changed my vagrant file as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24365338/2476294).

Comment: what do you mean they get changed ? what are the differences ? do you have any git hook defined ?

Comment: I've added an example in my question. There is no git hook defined. Thanks for help

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. All symlinks inside the repo are being reported as having a single line removed from them and that single line is the symlink destination.

Answer (score 0):

Is your guest VM Linux? Linux and Windows encode carriage returns differently. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to share a directory across different os environments. Each OS handles that differently and will operate on it differently. I suggest you do not try to handle the git repo from both sides through a shared folder

Instead, one way to fix this would be to host a bare repository on the shared folder and clone locally to the VM (and to the windows box). push/pull changes as necessary

**from host** (git for windows?)

```
cd shared/folder
mkdir <repo name>.git    #.git isn't really needed but is typical
cd <repo name>.git
git init --bare

cd <current repo location>
git remote add origin <path to repo.git folder>
git push --all
```

**from vm**

```
cd ~
git clone <path to shared folder bare repo.git>
```

be sure to set the username and email address when on the VM so that the commits are attributed to the correct people (using git config)