# Performing a npm install via Docker on a windows host

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, boot2docker

I'm trying to create a docker dev tools container for a devlopement environment on a windows host via docker toolbox but I have some trouble running the npm install command. 
It worked fine on a linux host but on the windows host I got the following error :

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.1.13-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /var/www/site/.npm/gulp/3.9.0/package.tgz.e87c24357cd6065ee71ce44c6f23673b
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/var/www/site/.npm/gulp/3.9.0/package.tgz.e87c24357cd6065ee71ce44c6f23673b' -> '/var/www/site/.npm/gulp/3.9.0/package.tgz'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 4.1.13-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.39d944b679d410e5293d6721cbc8287a
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename 'npm-debug.log.39d944b679d410e5293d6721cbc8287a' -> 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/site/npm-debug.log
```

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash node
RUN echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000" > /etc/sysctl.conf

ADD . /var/www/site
RUN chown -R node:node /var/www/site
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/local/lib/node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/local/bin

USER node
ENV HOME /var/www/site

WORKDIR /var/www/site

RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install --global gulp -y

EXPOSE 80 8080 35729
```

In Docker quickstart terminal, I use the following commands :

Building the image (works fine)

```
docker build -t dev_tools .
```

Building the container (works fine)

```
docker run --name=dev_tools_container -t --rm -v "//c/Users/Public/site:/var/www/site" --net=host dev_tools
```

Trying to install npm dependencies (shoots the error):

```
docker exec -it dev_tools_container npm install
```

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
RUN npm install --global gulp -y
```

use

```
RUN sudo npm install --global gulp -y
```

You try to install `gulp` as a global package from user `node` (not superuser).

Or install `gulp` before switch user to node.

```
USER node
RUN npm install --global gulp -y
```

## EDIT:

**boot2docker** is based on **VirtualBox**. Virtualbox does not allow symlinks on shared folders for security reasons.

To enable symlinks You must set **VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME** to **1**. (Here is link to description how to do it on Vargrant: [Symbolic links and synced folders in Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200333/symbolic-links-and-synced-folders-in-vagrant/24365338#24365338))

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

Replace VM_NAME and SHARE_NAME and restart VirtualBox.

Another solution is add `--no-bin-link` to `npm`:

```
RUN npm install -g bower --no-bin-link
RUN npm install --global gulp -y --no-bin-link
```

## EDIT 2

By default Windows 7 security policy does not allow creating symlinks as it's a potential security threat. If user is not in Administrators group run **secpol.msc** and navigate to **Local Policies-User Rights Assignments** and add your user to **Create symbolic links**.

If your user belongs to Administrators group then start `VirtualBox` with **Run as Administrator**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I tried but it changes nothing. This docker container works fine on a linux host. I think this is a trouble of shared folder. Also it is not the gulp or bower install that create problems :\

Comment: thank you again. I tried with the --no-bin-link option but without success. I'll see what I can do with symlinks

Comment: I ran the command  ./VBoxManage.exe setextradata default VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/c/Users 1
 in the /c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox folder but it had no effect :(

Comment: Your virtual machine has name `default` and shared forder has name `c/Users`? And You restart VirtualBox after this operation?

Comment: Yep exactly. Virtualbox told me that changes were made, I saved them and restart.

Comment: Let's try to simplify: rename share folder name to `cUsers`. Maybe VirtualBox have problem with this name?

Comment: Try to run VirtualBox "as an administrator"

Comment: again, thank you so much for your help, sorry for the answer delay, my user is already in the administrator group, I tried to re-do all the steps including SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate and executing virtualbox as an admin but I had the same issue..

Comment: Strangely, running the global npm commands went smoothly for me, but when trying `npm install` (which installs assets locally) i get thousands of errors about file permissions, mostly.

Answer (score 3):

You can mount node_modules as a volume, so it will be a Linux filesystem inside the Docker container. Add this to your Dockerfile:

`VOLUME /var/www/site/node_modules`

You will see the directory at `C:Users/Public/site/node_modules` because it is necessary for a mount point, but you will not see any contents unless you are inside the container.