# node command line tools are not compiled on vagrant

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant on Windows 10.
After installing all the dependecies with `npm install` (or `npm install --no-bin-links`, since I'm in Vagrant on Windows), `./node_modules/.bin` is empty. I expect to find there some command line tools.

In my case, it is `svg2png-many` that is missing.

I also tried to rebuild with `npm rebuild svg2png-many`, but this didn't create the missing file.

Note: I didn't get any error running `npm install`, simply the file is not there:

> ./svg2png.sh: line 8: ./node_modules/.bin/svg2png-many: No such file or directory

and this is in that file

```
for t in "${themes[@]}"
do
  echo "dist/img/${t}/"
  ./node_modules/.bin/svg2png-many -i "dist/img/${t}/" "dist/img/${t}/"
done
```

What should I try next ?

Comment: But you run the command with `--no-bin-links`, so the link are not created

Comment: @greuze If a run `npm install`, the cli files are not created either. Do you mean that the files in `./node_modules/.bin` are just symlinks ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, inside `./node_modules/.bin` there are symbolic links to the modules binaries. But `npm install` should download the modules in `./node_modules/<module>`

Comment: @greuze are you using virtualbox shared folder ? If so, then update the virtualbox guest additions in the guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are specifying `--no-bin-links`, the binaries are not going to be available in `./node_modules/.bin`, as they are symbolic links to modules binaries. You can see in [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> The **--no-bin-links** argument will prevent npm from creating symlinks
>   for any binaries the package might contain.

If you run `npm install` you should get all the modules in `package.json` file downloaded in `node_modules` folder. Here is an example of output (after installing without *--no-bin-links* flag):

```
$ ls -l node_modules/.bin
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 36 may 17 17:01 conventional-changelog -> ../conventional-changelog-cli/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 39 may 17 17:01 conventional-changelog-writer -> ../conventional-changelog-writer/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 37 may 17 17:01 conventional-commits-parser -> ../conventional-commits-parser/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 39 may 17 17:01 conventional-recommended-bump -> ../conventional-recommended-bump/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 34 may 17 17:01 cross-env -> ../cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 24 may 17 17:01 dateformat -> ../dateformat/bin/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 22 may 17 17:01 get-pkg-repo -> ../get-pkg-repo/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 25 may 17 17:01 git-raw-commits -> ../git-raw-commits/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 25 may 17 17:01 git-semver-tags -> ../git-semver-tags/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 28 may 17 17:01 handlebars -> ../handlebars/bin/handlebars
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 22 may 17 17:01 JSONStream -> ../JSONStream/index.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 21 may 17 17:01 lerna -> ../lerna/bin/lerna.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 20 may 17 17:00 mkdirp -> ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 39 may 17 17:01 npm-run-all -> ../npm-run-all/bin/npm-run-all/index.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 16 may 17 17:01 rimraf -> ../rimraf/bin.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 33 may 17 17:01 run-p -> ../npm-run-all/bin/run-p/index.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 33 may 17 17:01 run-s -> ../npm-run-all/bin/run-s/index.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 20 may 17 17:00 semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 51 may 17 17:01 sl-log-transformer -> ../strong-log-transformer/bin/sl-log-transformer.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 22 may 17 17:00 strip-indent -> ../strip-indent/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 25 may 17 17:01 uglifyjs -> ../uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ils ils 18 may 17 17:01 which -> ../which/bin/which
```

If you need to install a missing module, you can delete all downloaded dependencies before running `npm install`, or just install the dependency by running `npm install svg2png-many`.

I run the command and get the `svg2png-many` downloaded in `./node_modules/svg2png-many` and the binary file is present in `./node_modules/svg2png-many/bin/index.js`. You can run that file directly (instead of trying to use the symlink not created in `./node_modules/.bin`)

Important note: when using Vagrant on Windows, in order for `npm install` to work, you have to

- either run the console that starts `vagrant up` as administrator
- or use the option `--no-bin-links`

The first is obviously the required solution here.

Comment: You are right, the `--no-bin-links` option was the culprit. But this was not the primary reason. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200333/symbolic-links-and-synced-folders-in-vagrant `vagrant up` must be run as administrator, in order for `npm install` to be able to create symlinks.