# npm install causes errors like npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error on Debian

Tags: linux, node.js, gruntjs, npm, virtualbox

Installing Grunt as in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt-installing) shown, I first installed `grunt-cli` globally with `npm install -g grunt-cli` and now I'm trying to execute `npm install`, but only getting errors:

```
root@devvm:/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap# npm install
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/brace-expansion/1.1.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/delayed-stream/0.0.5/package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing form-data@0.1.4
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/is-property/1.0.2/package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing request@2.54.0
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-saucelabs/node_modules/sauce-tunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-http-upload.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open '/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-saucelabs/node_modules/sauce-tunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-http-upload.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open '/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-saucelabs/node_modules/sauce-tunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-http-upload.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-saucelabs/node_modules/sauce-tunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-http-upload.js' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.ba707f2a7a688e388708bbe88e2dd4ed
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno 62

npm ERR! ETXTBSY, rename 'npm-debug.log.ba707f2a7a688e388708bbe88e2dd4ed'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/npm-debug.log
```

I've just copied the project in a non-shared folder and started `npm install` again. And it worked. So, it seems to be a shared folder issue. But what exactly? [Symlinks are enabled](http://www.ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/) for this shared folder and I started the VM as admin (it helped, when I had similar issues installing Bower).

What is causing these errors and how to solve this problem?

> Environment: VirtualBox with Debian guest system and Windows 7 host system.

**EDIT**

Now (I think after I've successfully executed `npm install` in a non-shared folder) I'm geting different errors:

When I start the VM in the common way:

```
root@devvm:/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap# npm install
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/delayed-stream/0.0.5/package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing form-data@0.1.4
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/brace-expansion/1.1.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path ../semver/bin/semver
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1

npm ERR! UNKNOWN, symlink '../semver/bin/semver'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.428531818e2d916d5ae79bdf94dd73b3
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno 62

npm ERR! ETXTBSY, rename 'npm-debug.log.428531818e2d916d5ae79bdf94dd73b3'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/npm-debug.log
```

When I start the VM as `Administrator`:

```
root@devvm:/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap# npm install
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/delayed-stream/0.0.5/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/brace-expansion/1.1.0/package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing form-data@0.1.4
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/fs-extra/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/once/node_modules/wrappy
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1

npm ERR! UNKNOWN, mkdir '/var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/fs-extra/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/once/node_modules/wrappy'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.0bb66467f3aae813a34e03a797f8da19
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno 62

npm ERR! ETXTBSY, rename 'npm-debug.log.0bb66467f3aae813a34e03a797f8da19'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/axit/portfolio/public/bower_components/bootstrap/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I didn't try to replicate your issue yet, but first I would like to ask you a question: Have you tried to run the command using `sudo`? Because this line `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` seems to suggest that. Something like `sudo npm install` maybe is the solution.

Comment: I am `root` on the Debian guest system. And I've also started the VM as `Administrator` on the host.

Comment: Not sure, but in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23526288/4594377) and the comments below, they suggest to use an additional option `--no-bin-link`. You said that you've had problem when installing Bower, maybe just enabling the symlinks wasn't enough.

Comment: Just tried it out. No, it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 10):

Ok I see the solution

```
 sudo npm cache clean
```

Then

```
sudo npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```

I did this on MacOS

Comment: Thanks for the tips. For me, I have to invoke  the command with a `-f` option :  `npm cache clean -f`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your hard drive is not full. That was my case.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing `sudo npm cache clean`. But It looks the problem is the path is too long for windows (260byte limit) so you can't share the directory.

I tried using [fenestrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fenestrate) but it didn't work out for me. You may also want to check [this entry](https://github.com/Snugug/Aurora/issues/43).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After a lot of attempts it finally worked. Somehow... I don't remember anymore, I think, I used a workaround, but don't remember, what it exactly was. Anyway, if I have this issue again, I will try your solution out and give a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and the following did not immediately resolve the issue:

```
npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

It turns out I had run out of disk space on my virtual machine. After allocating some more space and running above commands everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for hint about space. Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and I tried all the options suggested here without succcess. Finally, I read somewhere that, I should have superuser permissions, so I did

```
 sudo -s
```

and it seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Probably better to change the permissions on the folder to be owned by your user rather than using sudo. Sudo is less safe and overall not recommended (as it has super user status)

Answer (score 0):

To me **npm cache clean** didn't work.
However removing the problematic directory (**npm remove**) and then simply reinstalling the package did!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried install modules inside vagrant, nothing above didn't work, so I tried install it on host (OSX) and it worked.